# Error when exiting Powershell Core remote session

Tags: powershell

I am running into a SOAP error when I am exiting out of a PowerShell remote session where I am remoting from a Windows 10 system to a Ubuntu 16.04 server. Is there a way to fix or silence this error?

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Closing the remote server shell instance failed with the following error message : <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Receiver</SOAP-ENV:Value><SOAP-ENV:Subcode><SOAP-ENV:Value>wsman:InternalError</SOAP-ENV:Value></SOAP-ENV:Subcode></SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Reason><SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en-US"/></SOAP-ENV:Reason></SOAP-ENV:Fault> For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

On the Ubuntu server, I currently have installed Open Management Infrastructure version 1.4.2-1, PowerShell Remoting Protocol version 1.4.1-28, and PowerShell Core 6.0.1. For this setup I followed the instructions laid out on the following website: https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-between-windows-and-linux/

This is how I consistently reproduce the error:

```
## Setup Credentials to connect to PowerShell on remote Linux server
$credentials = Get-Credential

## Disable cert checking (for now)
$sessionOptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipRevocationCheck -SkipCNCheck

## Start the remote session
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ServerName -Credential $credentials -Authentication basic -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOptions

## Exit out of the remote session
exit

## This is the error I receive on exit:
Closing the remote server shell instance failed with the following error message : <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Receiver</SOAP-ENV:Value><SOAP-ENV:Subcode><SOAP-ENV:Value>wsman:InternalError</SOAP-ENV:Value></SOAP-ENV:Subcode></SOAP-ENV:Code><SOAP-ENV:Reason><SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en-US"/></SOAP-ENV:Reason></SOAP-ENV:Fault> For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running into this issue, I found that instead of typing "exit" I needed to use "Exit-PSSession" and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm glad that using `Exit-PSSession` fixed the problem, but using `exit` isn't bad form: the two commands _should_ be interchangeable, and if they're not, it is a _bug_. It seems that `Exit-PSSession` primarily exists for symmetry with `Enter-PSSession`; from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/exit-pssession): "You can also use the `Exit` keyword to end an interactive session. The effect is the same as using `Exit-PSSession`".

Answer (score 0):

Dont get the solution because Microsoft says on Exit-PSSession page that
You can also use the Exit keyword to end an interactive session. The effect is the same as using Exit-PSSession.
Anyway i get the same trouble on my WIN 2016 with PS5.1 remoting to SLES x64 12.2 with PS6 even if i run Exit-PSSession.

Comment: I know in my situation I was running powershell core on my windows system and my linux system. I would recommend running the same version of powershell on both systems.